# invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Stream*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: arduino, esp32

i have a problem with my ESP32 code. My ESP-32 code connected with PMS5003 dust sensor. I want to combine the PMS5003 code with existing program code. I got an error (invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Stream*' [-fpermissive]) with program code like this :

```
struct pms5003data {
  uint16_t framelen;
  uint16_t pm10_standard, pm25_standard, pm100_standard;
  uint16_t pm10_env, pm25_env, pm100_env;
  uint16_t particles_03um, particles_05um, particles_10um, particles_25um, particles_50um, particles_100um;
  uint16_t unused;
  uint16_t checksum;
};
struct pms5003data data;

void PMS5003(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  while(key != '#'){
    currentTime = millis();
    key = keypad.getKey();
    if((currentTime - lastTime) > 2000){
      Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
      if (readPMSdata(&&Serial1)){
        menu.lcd->clear();
        menu.lcd->setCursor(0,0);
        menu.lcd->print("Particle 0.3: "); menu.lcd->println(data.particles_03um);
        menu.lcd->setCursor(0,1);
        menu.lcd->print("Particle 0.5: "); menu.lcd->println(data.particles_05um);
        menu.lcd->setCursor(0,2);
        menu.lcd->print("Particle 10: "); menu.lcd->println(data.particles_10um);
      }  
      lastTime = currentTime;
    }  
//    menu.lcd->setCursor(0,2);
//    menu.lcd->print(menu.isInEditMode());
    }
    menu.back();
    menu.resetMenu(); 
}

boolean readPMSdata(Stream *s) {
  if (! s->available()) {
    return false;
  }
 
  // Read a byte at a time until we get to the special '0x42' start-byte
  if (s->peek() != 0x42) {
    s->read();
    return false;
  }
 
  // Now read all 32 bytes
  if (s->available() < 32) {
    return false;
  }
 
  uint8_t buffer[32];
  uint16_t sum = 0;
  s->readBytes(buffer, 32);
 
  // get checksum ready
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    sum += buffer[i];
  }
 
  /* debugging
    for (uint8_t i=2; i<32; i++) {
    Serial.print("0x"); Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX); Serial.print(", ");
    }
    Serial.println();
  */
 
  // The data comes in endian'd, this solves it so it works on all platforms
  uint16_t buffer_u16[15];
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    buffer_u16[i] = buffer[2 + i * 2 + 1];
    buffer_u16[i] += (buffer[2 + i * 2] << 8);
  }
 
  // put it into a nice struct :)
  memcpy((void *)&data, (void *)buffer_u16, 30);
 
  if (sum != data.checksum) {
    Serial.println("Checksum failure");
    return false;
  }
  // success!
  return true;
}
```

Guess why and what is the solution?

The error says that it cannot convert void into stream

Comment: Post the entire error message.  You are paraphrasing it and leaving out some important information.  Don't ever try to summarize the compiler.  Just copy and paste what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have one too many & in this line

```
if (readPMSdata(&&Serial1)){
```

Make it:

```
if (readPMSdata(&Serial1)){
```

Comment: Hey, it's working. It turned out that when I entered the program code, I experienced a typo in writing the program code hahaha. Thanks a lot man